# Trying to figure out return code 2 from Hive insert into statement

Tags: hive, insert, mapreduce, impala

I understand this return code for a MapReduce task is fairly generic, but I have been having trouble accessing the Hadoop UI/job dashboard as I don't have the right permissions so I am unable to view the detailed logs.

What I was doing: an `INSERT INTO ___ SELECT FROM` statement in hive to insert data from an existing partitioned table into the same one but with an updated schema. I then tried a similar insert command using impala and it worked.

I know this is limited info, but as I cannot view the detailed logs to figure out why it didn't work, are there any common explanations for this? One I found, for example, was a memory/resource issue. Are there any other explanations?

Comment: "are there any common explanations for this? "  - No common explanations. "Memory issues" makes no sense because it can be something else. You need failed container logs.

Comment: like above comment, memory issue in impala is very tricky to resolve. I would say, 1. reduce amount of data insert by putting filters. 2. check the select clause if it uses lots of tables/joins. 3. run at a time when system is not busy. Impala is in memory processor so when there are lots of data to process it crashes saying memory error.